# WPF + PRISM - should I inject WCF client into View-Model?

Tags: wpf, wcf, dependency-injection

I have a WPF application in PRISM architecture.

From what I read on the net, I saw that it is best if the View-Models call WCF service operation i n an **ASYNC** manner, and also - it is best to **create a new connection for each operation**. (I was told it is not good to keep connections alive for too long).

My question is - how should I inject the WCF clients to my View-Model ?

If I simply create an interface for the 'auto-generated' client - and inject the interface - this will simply create an instance for the client in my View-Model constructor, but that will not help me if I want to create a new client for each operation I perform in the window.

For that - I need something like a 'client factory' to be injected.

Can anyone offer his opinion on this ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, IMVHO the WCF call is best to go in the Model, not the ViewModel.

You can create a factory helper class, you pass it an interface and it passes back a concrete instance that implements that interface. The factory helper can still use PRISM to resolve the interface to a concrete type, the types will resolve whatever you have registered them to, and you will get a new instance each time provided you haven't registered them with a lifetime manager.

Using PRISM inside the factory helper helps keep the whole thing highly unit testable - you can mock out the WCF related proxy classes at test time, and the target Model will never know the difference. If you really want to follow the [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) pattern then you could inject the factory helper on the constructor.

Comment: Problem is - I am using MEF to do the bootstrapping, and MEF does not support 'generic object' such as 'templated factories'. Any other ideas ?

Comment: @John use MEF to load the modules, then use Prism to resolve/load the various views/viewmodels. Or if you don't want to mix the two, drop MEF and use Prism [to load your modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29).